# Item Format Validate In .NET2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, types

I need to validate each of item formats below. Suppose user input Only One value a time, I must find out which format he/her input. I there any easy to approach it?

Thanks for your suggestions and comments.

*.NET 2.0 installed. C# Used.*

```
2 byte character
8 byte integer (signed)
1 byte integer (signed)
2 byte integer (signed)
4 byte integer (signed)
8 byte floating point
4 byte floating point
8 byte integer (unsigned)
1 byte integer (unsigned)
2 byte integer (unsigned)
4 byte integer (unsigned)
```

Comment: Do you mean that yout want to find the least memory intensive variant for the input? If not, how will you decide which format the number 1 should adhere to?

Comment: Assuming that I just need match the single value to each of items above. It doesn't matter the sequence of the each items.

Comment: what if the user enters `hello world`, that wouldn't fall under any of your classifications. What should happen then?

Comment: @Matt Ellen, I will handle "`helloworld`" with `ASCII` format. Or reject '`hello world` as an invalid ASCII string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `TryParse` static methods of all of the following types:

- Byte
- SByte
- Int16
- UInt16
- Int32
- UInt32
- Int64
- UInt64
- Single
- Double

For characters, you will have to be more specific -- do you want the input converted by character (e.g. if they enter `5` the character value will be 53, the ASCII value representing the digit 5), or by value (e.g. they would have to enter `53` to produce the digit 5)?

Comment: I think I take the option 2. By value.

Comment: In that case, just bundle the code together with the success path for `UInt16.TryParse()`.  Since `ushort` and `char` are relatively interchangeable, just cast the resultant `ushort` to `char` if the parsing succeeds.